# UIDatePicker Moving up tableview content

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have a `UIViewController` with a Navigation bar and also a `UITableView` in it. I have button in the view controller that when it is pressed pops up a `UIDatePicker`. However, When i press the button to pop up the `UIDatePicker`, all my content in the tableview moves up about 30 pixels. Not cool. I want the `UIDatePicker` to just popup overtop the view controller without shifting any elements. Here is the code of my date picker. Thoughts?

```
- (IBAction)timeWasPressed:(id)sender {

if(self.pickerShown == NO){
    self.slidePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    self.slidePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    self.slidePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];


    [self.view addSubview:self.slidePicker];

    //make done button
    self.toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,64)];
    self.toolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                     action:@selector(doneButton)];

    self.toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
    barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.pickerShown = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.toolBar];
}
 }

-(void)doneButton{

NSDate *pickerDate = [self.slidePicker date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *selectionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter    stringFromDate:pickerDate]]; //
[self.timeButton setTitle:selectionString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

self.pickerShown = NO;

[self.slidePicker removeFromSuperview];
[self.toolBar removeFromSuperview];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What jason said is right, but he forgot to say you'll have to erase the line

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

And so, you'll have to replace

```
//....
[self.view addSubview:self.slidePicker];
//...
[self.view addSubview:self.toolBar];
//...
```

with

```
//...
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.slidePicker];
//...
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.toolBar];
//...
```

So your "timeWasPressed:" code will be:

```
self.slidePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.slidePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
self.slidePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.slidePicker];

//make done button
self.toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,64)];
self.toolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(doneButton)];

self.toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.pickerShown = YES;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.toolBar];
```

Don't forget you can also remove the

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

from your doneButton method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You rock Klash, this works! Can you give me a brief explanation of what was happening the way I was doing it in comparison to yours, just so i can better understand the situation for the future. Kind of a noob here.

Comment: Sure @Srmuhs! The NavigationController is holding your ViewController, so you can think that the ViewContoroller is one of its "subviews"(subViewController for true). So instead adding the toolBar and DatePicker inside your ViewController(where you want to show the NavicationBar), we add them in front of the whole ViewController. The problem you were experiencing was that the view that is holding your tableView resizes when there's no NavigationBar and the tableView reajusts its size keeping the 0px distance from Top of your view

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why everything shifts up is because you are hiding the navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Replace that line with the following and if you see everything animating up then this is the reason why everything is shifting.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true animated:true];
```

If you want the date picker to show over the navigation controller then instead of adding it to the view controller's view, add the picker to the navigation controller's view instead.

So.. replace

```
[self.view addSubview:self.slidePicker];
```

with..

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.slidePicker];
```

Hope it works out.